# Android getting layout to dynamically position and space elements within a layout

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout:

```
begin RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    TextView 
begin LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    4 - 6 radio buttons  variable number

end LinearLayout
  TextView
end RelativeLayout
```

So when there are six radio buttons it displays fine.  When there are only 4 they move up to the top and I would like them centered.  I did not find a   android:layout_alignParentCenter="true" or middle option for the LinearLayout itself so it would goto the center to of the screen.  Individually the radio button elements make up 4-6 elements variably.  So how do I get these 4 elements positioned in the center of the linear layout or the linear layout centered within the screen.   Thanks

Comment: so now I am in a relative layout and i want to express that element should be equally spaced between two elements essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` on your `LinearLayout`?

You would probably need to set the `LinearLayout` to use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for this to work.